# Sorting by a related table

Tags: php, laravel-4

If I do this,

```
Booking::query()->with('vehicle')
```

Laravel generates two queries:

```
select * from `bookings` 
select * from `vehicles` where `vehicles`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Can I tell Laravel to do a `LEFT JOIN` instead so that I can do an `orderBy` on `vehicles.name`? Each booking only has one vehicle, so it wouldn't generate any extra records.

I'm aware that I can do `DB::table('booking')->leftJoin` instead, but then it doesn't populate my models.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do. First is to change your query to:

```
Booking::leftJoin('vehicle', 'vehicle.booking_id', '=', 'booking.id')->get(); // or whatever your fields are
```

The other is to sort the collection after you get your results. There is a good example in the documentation. Check it here : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections 
Hope that helps

Comment: I didn't think Eloquent models supported `leftJoin`? `leftJoin` isn't anywhere on that page.

Comment: Well, it does support it. And just an advice, if you have begger tables with lots of data, it's a good idea to use joins rather than eager and lazy loading. I recently had lots of headaches with this